# Burg bootloader Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, burg

Hello I'm a relatively new ubuntu user and I'm having some trouble with the burg bootloader. The issue is that when I choose the ubuntu option it works 1/3 of the time without any trouble but sometimes the resolution when I get to ubuntu is weird and half the screen is not shown and sometimes it doesn't start at all but freezes on a black screen. I've tried changing the resolution in burg, even reinstalling ubuntu but nothing seems to help.

I find Burg a nice alternative to grub so I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you look at grub logs and see if there are any errors, also how are you configuring burg on install? I use burg and have never had any trouble. I suspect that it is either a hardware issue with your machine or you are making a mistake with your setup. This is the tutorial i followed that worked for me: http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/ubuntu/brug-and-theme-configuration.html